# How can I define a redirect_to url after payment?

Tags: php, html, algorithm, security

I have a hidden input into my payment form like this:

```
<form action="<bank_api>">
    <input type="number" name="amount" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<current_url>" />
</form>
```

And I will use it like this after paying:

```
header("location: " . $_GET['redirect_to']);
```

---

Everything works as well, just I feel a security problem:

A user can simply change the value of that hidden input (an set the url of another website) before submitting the form and then it will be redirect to that website after paying. See? My server will send a request to another website. Is that fine or I have to put some check-domain-name before redirecting?

Comment: Store the redirect URL in server side like either in database or session or ENV config like laravel. Not in HTML. .

Comment: If you know the URL when you send the HTML page, then why even send it to the client? Store it in a session and retrieve it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Store the redirect_url in the $_SESSION and retrieve and delete it after the form submission.